# Wordpress - Hide Theme Options from other admin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a template and I am currently trying to find a solution or method to effectively hide the THEME OPTIONS located in APPEARANCE from another admin user?

I would not like to strip my co-admin from his "admin privileges" and change him to a lower class however I am seeking a possibility to hide this element from him so that he can't change the main theme options/settings.

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much,
Patrick

Comment: Is it your own theme? you (probably) have to edit the theme to do this. Is hiding enough? or do you really want to close the page?

Comment: It's a custom theme yes - I would merely seek a function to hide this specific element from a specific user id (e.g. my other admin).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the built in Wordpress function remove_submenu_page in a function which checked for a specific user ID.  You would hook that to admin_head.

```
<?php

function hide_menu() {
 global $current_user;
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 // echo "user:".$user_id;   // Use this to find your user id quickly

    if($user_id != '1') {

        // To remove the whole Appearance admin menu you would use;
        remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );

        // To remove the theme editor and theme options submenus from
        // the Appearance admin menu, as well as the main 'Themes'
        // submenu you would use 

        remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php' );
        remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme-editor.php' );
        remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'theme_options' );

    }
}

add_action('admin_head', 'hide_menu');
?>
```

However, it should be noted (as per the comments) that using this only hides the menu item it doesn't completely disable it and it could be accessed directly from the browser.  If you really have to keep this other person as an administrator rather than a user with lower privileges, and you have to make sure they cannot access the theme options at all then you should think about using a plugin to create a new user access level with custom capabilities (I say use a plugin as I don't believe there's any point in coding that up yourself, you are just reinventing the wheel).

Comment: WOW - thank you very much McNab - I will definately see into this. Thanks again for your detailed explanation!

Comment: No worries - hope you can successfully keep this other guy from messing up your site! :)

Comment: this does mean if yo would go to /wp-admin/theme.php he will still see the page.

Comment: @janw - Yes you are right, this is a good point. Patrick, he can access the page directly using this approach - in this case themes.php?page=theme_options.  It depends how technical this other administrator is, it might be worth even creating another user access level and assigning him to that.

Comment: I have just tried to integrate one of the codes below (the second one) into my theme_functions.php , however I ended up getting a white screen of death. Any ideas?

Comment: Also I have noted that THEME OPTIONS does not have a unique ID. APPEARANCE has an id - <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top menu-icon-appearance menu-top-first" id="menu-appearance"> but THEME OPTIONS specifically would look like: <li><a href='themes.php?page=options-framework' tabindex="1">Theme Options</a></li><li>. How can I proceed from there?

Comment: Patrick you are right - that was a bad answer for a submenu page, I have updated it. I hope this works better for you, sorry about that.

Comment: Absolutely no worries McNab, I am very greatful for the help you are giving me. I have some progress now, it seems to be working for some part but not entirely: I have seen to create a demo user and add your function (which should remove themes and theme-editor) to restrict his access. It works by removing the theme editor, however the page THEMES, and theme options are both still visible. Do you have any ideas or am I doing something wrong? Thanks again for your insights and great help!

Comment: We're getting there!  I've edited my answer again and have been testing it out to make sure it works so there's no more edits :)

Comment: you're truly excellent McNab - thank you very much, that made my day! I wish you all the best and a great day ahead, Patrick!!!

Comment: Hahah sorry - last edit: It is working now , however the changes are globally to all users which includes me. Let me explain: Let's say my evil admin companion is called "wally". If I try your method and replace 'patrick' with 'wally' nothing really happens. On the other hand if I change 'patrick' to 'lala' (an user which is actually NOT registered) the changes are applied, but globally. Any ideas? Sorry to bother McNab :)

Comment: Lol, this is embarassing now!  OK, edited it again, I've changed it to use the user ID instead of the user name and it's working well for me. Any more and we better dive onto chat, this thread has turned into a monster courtesy of my lazy testing.  Good luck with it.

Comment: Working fine now ! Thanks McNab for your OUTSTANDING help - god bless!!